# How to draw a border on a FireMonkey TListView object

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

If you drop a *FMX.TStringGrid* onto a new FireMonkey form, the grid gets shown with a thin border.

If you drop a *FMX.TTListView* onto the form, there is no border.

Neither component seems to have a property for enabling/disabling the border, or setting the border colour or width.

I assume this is due to the cross-platform requirement, so how should it be done? Do I need to add a panel, then put the listview inside the panel? Or is it something to do with the style, as in needing a *TStyleBook*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `TListView` has no border. Firemonkey offers several ways to add a border to any visual control. For adding a simple border I would not try to change the styles.

In my opinion, the simplest solution is to put a rectangle from the palette (from Shapes) into the form.
Set in the rectangle the `Stroke` to the desired color and thickness.
As the next step, go to the structure-view in the designer and move the `Listview` as a child element into this rectangle. Change the `Align` property of the listview to `Client`. 
To display the border-lines again, you must set all the values ​​for `Padding` (bottom, left, right and top) of the rectangle to the value thickness of the rectangle stroke.

If you like you can also add a `TShadowEffect` on your rectangle or listview control.

Comment: Best solution. FMX relies heavily on "stacking" components to achieve the desired look&feel.